# Make a whole view with sub-elements clickable

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a vertical LinearLayout in my app where every row should get a more complex sub-view consisting of an image and two lines of text. Now I want to make the complete row clickable in order to start an other action. This means the whole thing should react on a click: the base view which holds the other elements, the image and even the two lines of text.

My question: what is the best approach for this? I can't use a simple button for the complete row and as far as I know I can't set an onClick-Handler for view/image/labels?

Any idea how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your layout and related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add clickable tag true in xml to your main view eg relativelayout or linearlayout.
That will work

Comment: FYI this will work in most cases, but beware on child views that are clickable by default, like Button, ImageButton, etc. they'll block the click from going into the parent view when they're clicked

Comment: Thanks @marmor. 
Yes I do know that. buttons and imagebuttons are placed in main view for click events.

If you don't want clicks better use texviews/imageview.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option would be to put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your parent view, this will block any child view from taking clicks from the parent, then put a click listener on the parent only.
This is assuming you don't care on which child view exactly the user clicked within the parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
    <TextView
        ... />
    <ImageButton
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in code:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
parent.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: This sounds good but doesn't work for me on a ConstraintLayout with a MaterialButton inside

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Just loop over the childen and make then non clickable. This works even if you are using clickable items inside root view.

```kotlin
rootView.apply {
    descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS
    isClickable = true
    setOnClickListener {
        Snackbar.make(it, "$data", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    children.forEach {
        it.isClickable = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).